# iPhone: Looking for an API to store survey results

Tags: iphone, network-programming

In my iPhone app I am trying to gather feedback on my game via an optional survey. I would like to send this data to a central server, where I could gather all the statistics and process them to have a bar chart or other convenient presentation.

The data being sent an integer representing the user's preference. ie) Given "How did you like our game?", the user could select from a button from :) :\ :(    . Eventually I would also like to have audio feedback where the user could record their voice. The variable length sound clip would be sent and stored from an iPhone to some server, for playback later.

Has anybody done something similar? Google Spreadsheets offers an API which I can't make heads nor tails of but I think it will support a tally of responses. ie) I received 10 goods, 4 neutral, and 7 poor ratings. As far as I can tell I wouldn't be able to store a sound clip in a spreadsheet.

I also looked into Google App engine but if possible I'd like to avoid the networking code to transmit the survey data and the server side scripts to interpret the data. Can somebody recommend a simple API that I could use to store integers for viewing? Ideally I'd like to say something simple like

```
if (response == "Good") MyGoogleSpreadsheet.MyAppStats.Increment(positiveResponseTallyCell);
```

Later on I'd just log into Googlespreadsheets and the results would be there for me to read. By the way I don't have to necessarily use a spreadsheet. I just want this to be easy. Bonus points if the API supports the storage and playback of sound but integers will suffice for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Flurry API (flurry.com) which lets you specify which custom events to log, and gives you charts and downloadable CSV. Very easy to use:

```
[FlurryAPI startSession: flurryID];
[FlurryAPI logEvent:@"QUESTION1" withParameters:@"Good"];
```

Although Flurry is made for general usage statistics gathering, I think it would be a quick and easy way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you've already taken a look at the Google Spreadsheets API, but you may not have seen the [GData Objective-C framework](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) which includes support for reading/writing to and from Google Docs spreadsheets (via the `GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet` class).